# Сравнить две строки-массива в sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть две строки: `word1` и `word2`

Внутри них массив неких данных связанных между собой например:

```
CREATE TABLE logs (
    word1 string,    
    word2 string
    );

INSERT INTO logs (Word1, Word2) 
VALUES ('['location','title','value']', ['Москва','заголовок1','34']);

INSERT INTO logs (Word1, Word2) 
VALUES ('['title','value','location']', ['Заголовок999','574584','Тверь']);
```

То есть каждый по порядку элемент в первой строке по своему номеру в массиве привязан к значению в другом массиве второй строки.

Вопрос: как мне определить номер в массиве значения например `location` в первой строке, и соотнести его с таким же порядковым номером в массиве из второй строки, при том что порядок слов и их значение в массиве может меняться?
На выходе если брать поле `location` исходя из примера выше нужно получить поле `location` с данными:

```
Москва
Тверь
```

И т.д.

Comment: @Akina, исправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE logs (
    word1 VARCHAR[3],    
    word2 VARCHAR[3]
    );

INSERT INTO logs (Word1, Word2) VALUES 
('{"location","title","value"}', '{"Москва","заголовок1","34"}'),
('{"title","value","location"}', '{"Заголовок999","574584","Тверь"}');

SELECT *, 
       array_position(Word1, 'location') location_position,
       Word2[array_position(Word1, 'location')] location_value
FROM logs;
```

| word1 | word2 | location_position | location_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {location,title,value} | {Москва,заголовок1,34} | 1 | Москва |
| {title,value,location} | {Заголовок999,574584,Тверь} | 3 | Тверь |

https://sqlize.online/sql/psql15/a8f10c996dfb9a95bfda968c9eeccfa3/

Comment: подскажите если ли аналог функции array_position для Oracle?

Comment: @CarryS Вот понятия не имею. Но, поскольку Оракл вроде не имеет встроенного типа "массив", мне весьма сомнительно..